# Get selectize.js to show optgroup headers

Tags: jquery, json, selectize.js, optgroup

I have a .json file containing US city data. I have successfully pulled the data into my selectize select box, but it does not display the optgroup headers. Here is an excerpt of the .json file:

```
[
    [...],
    [{
        "Index": 16246,
        "Display": "Auburn",
        "City": "Auburn",
        "County": "Lee",
        "State": "Alabama",
        "StateAbbv": "AL",
        "Latitude": 32.5475,
        "Longitute": -85.4682,
        "Zipcode": 36830
    }, {
        "Index": 16247,
        "Display": "Auburn",
        "City": "Auburn",
        "County": "Lee",
        "State": "Alabama",
        "StateAbbv": "AL",
        "Latitude": 32.5782,
        "Longitute": -85.349,
        "Zipcode": 36831
    }, {
        "Index": 16248,
        "Display": "Auburn",
        "City": "Auburn",
        "County": "Lee",
        "State": "Alabama",
        "StateAbbv": "AL",
        "Latitude": 32.592,
        "Longitute": -85.5189,
        "Zipcode": 36832
    }],
    [{
        "Index": 16249,
        "Display": "Auburn University",
        "City": "AuburnUniversity",
        "County": "Lee",
        "State": "Alabama",
        "StateAbbv": "AL",
        "Latitude": 32.6024,
        "Longitute": -85.4873,
        "Zipcode": 36849
    }],
[...]
]
```

As you can see, there are three entries for Auburn, so I want "Auburn" to be the optgroup header and the three entries (displaying zipcodes) to be underneath it. I included a singular entry (Auburn University) that should also display the same way, but only with the single zipcode.

This is basically the format I am looking for in the dropdown:

```
AUBURN
  36380
  36831
  36832
AUBURN UNIVERSITY
  36849
```

Here is what I have set up on my page to configure the plugin:

```
$select_city = $('#zipcode-select').selectize({
    optgroupField: 'Display',
    optgroupLabelField: 'Display',
    optgroupValueField: 'Index',
    maxItems: zipcodeLimit,
    valueField: 'Zipcode',
    labelField: 'Zipcode',
    searchField: ['Zipcode','Display']
});
```

Currently it just outputs the zipcodes:

[image: default]

Since I specified to search in both the 'Display' and 'Zipcode' fields, I can search for either the zipcode or the city and it will filter accordingly:

[image: zipcode search]
[image: display search]

According to the [plugin's usage page](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md), I was led to believe supplying the `optgroup*` options would achieve what I am looking to do, but apparently that is not so.

Does anyone know how to implement what I am seeking to do?

Answer (score 4):

Detail information: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/optgroups.html

```js
  $('#inputprocplantemp').selectize({
                options: [
                    { class: 'mammal', value: "dog", name: "Dog" },
                    { class: 'mammal', value: "cat", name: "Cat" },
                    { class: 'mammal', value: "horse", name: "Horse" },
                    { class: 'mammal', value: "kangaroo", name: "Kangaroo" },
                    { class: 'bird', value: 'duck', name: 'Duck' },
                    { class: 'bird', value: 'chicken', name: 'Chicken' },
                    { class: 'bird', value: 'ostrich', name: 'Ostrich' },
                    { class: 'bird', value: 'seagull', name: 'Seagull' },
                    { class: 'reptile', value: 'snake', name: 'Snake' },
                    { class: 'reptile', value: 'lizard', name: 'Lizard' },
                    { class: 'reptile', value: 'alligator', name: 'Alligator' },
                    { class: 'reptile', value: 'turtle', name: 'Turtle' }
                ],
                optgroups:
                    [
                       { value: 'mammal', label: 'Mammal', label_scientific: 'Mammalia' },
                       { value: 'bird', label: 'Bird', label_scientific: 'Aves' },
                       { value: 'reptile', label: 'Reptile', label_scientific: 'Reptilia' }
                    ]
                ,
                optgroupField: 'class',
                labelField: 'name',
                searchField: ['name', 'class'],
                maxItems:1,
                render: {
                    optgroup_header: function (data, escape) {
                        return '<div class="optgroup-header">' + escape(data.label) + ' <span class="scientific">' + escape(data.label_scientific) + '</span></div>';
                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are successfully returning the data from your JSON file to the `options` array in your selectize function (though I can't tell for sure from the code snippet you provided). I am guessing that what you are missing is to include the `optgroups` data, so that the group headers will be displayed in your dropdown.

Following is an example of how to include `optgroups` and the corresponding field, label and value properties you will need:

```
$('select-id').selectize({
  // this is where you are returning the data from your JSON file
  options: [
    {itemGroup: 'Group A', itemValue: '1', itemName: 'Item 1'},
    {itemGroup: 'Group A', itemValue: '2', itemName: 'Item 2'},
    {itemGroup: 'Group B', itemValue: '3', itemName: 'Item 3'},
    {itemGroup: 'Group B', itemValue: '4', itemName: 'Item 4'}
  ],
  // this is the data that I think you are probably missing
  optgroups: [
    {groupName: 'Group A'},
    {groupName: 'Group B'}
  ],
  optgroupField: 'itemGroup', // refers to the group field in "options"
  optgroupLabelField: 'groupName', // refers to the label field in "optgroups"
  optgroupValueField: 'groupName', // refers to the value field in "optgroups"
  valueField: 'itemValue',
  labelField: 'itemName',
  searchField: ['itemGroup', 'itemName']
});
```